# Make Line Chart Dynamic From JSON File Using Chartjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, chart.js

I am trying to change 3 charts that I have from static charts to dynamic charts. I'd like them to read one data point every 5 seconds but can't figure out how to use interval correctly.

I am taking this over from someone else and have never done angular projects before this.

I've tried to figure out how to put an interval in and I am not sure where it should go. I've tried in the ngOnInit() to put setInterval
around pipe but I am not doing it right. Now I have tried interval from 'rxjs' library.
 Everything I've tried has just given me a blank chart instead of dynamic chart or an error. The charts show all the data correctly I just can't figure out how to have them plotted one at a time instead of all at once.

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';

      ngOnInit() {
 this.DataService.Data$.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).interval(5000).subscribe(data => {
          this.participantsData$ = this.DataService.combineChartData$([
            this.DataService.getChartData(data, 'Peers', {
            label: 'Peers',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
           }),
```

I expect the interval to plot one value from JSON object at a time every 5 seconds.

under my class I have Observable like this:

```
participantsData$: Observable<ChartData>;
  participantsOptions: LineChartWidgetOptions = {
    ...this.defaultChartOptions,
    title: 'Participants',
  };
```

I get this error for what I have written above:

```
error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
```

I try delay too and I get the same error. From my understanding Interval is a static method and I can't use it this way but why doesn't `delay` work? I can provide more code if needed but I think I am just not understanding something fundamental here about how observable works or how pipe and subscribe work.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Edit to add more information this is in my `service.ts`:

```
combineChartData(chartData: ChartData[]): ChartData {
    const labels = flatMap(chartData, (value, index, collection) => {
      return value['labels'];
    });

    const dataSets = flatMap(chartData, (value, index, collection) => {
      return value['datasets'];
    });

    const result = {
      labels: uniqWith(labels, isEqual),
      datasets: dataSets,
    } as ChartData;

    return result;
  }


  combineChartData$(chartData: ChartData[]): Observable<ChartData> {

     const chartDataOnDelay = of(this.combineChartData(chartData));
     //chartDataOnDelay;
     return chartDataOnDelay;
  }
```

Comment: need the code for this.DataService.Data$, is it a stream of data or a one off http call

Comment: It is data from a .json file that is located in the project file.

Comment: I think I need to maybe try multicasting like this documentation but I am struggling to implement it correctly https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the other way round if you want to read the endpoint at a specific interval repeatedly

```
import {interval} from 'rxjs'
interval(5000).pipe(switchMap(()=>this.DataService.Data$)).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: I get a ````Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Ope
ratorFunction<{}, any>'.````

Comment: missed the parentheses. updated the answer. You should see something log to console every 5 sec

Comment: I get no data printed the charts are blank with this implementation. I will update my question with more information. I appreciate the help. I've been struggling with this all week.

Comment: you got to check whether  this.DataService.Data$ return anything first. try  this.DataService.Data$.subscribe(console.log)

Comment: Okay I will check.

Comment: It does not print anything to console but this:``this.DataService.Data$.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(//code//)`` prints the chart as expected. But it shows all data points on the chart

Comment: it means you this.DataService.Data$ is not correctly return data. You will have to check this method first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196452/discussion-between-ella-and-fan-cheung).

Comment: Okay I did test and it works and returns json values in console but they do not print to graph.